# Django insert False but get sql True

Tags: python, sql, django, database, sqlite

```
             user=articleread1.objects.latest('id');
             user.paid='False';user.save()
```

But sql command look like this with True values

```
QUERY = u'UPDATE "wiki_articleread" SET "current_revision_id" = NULL, "readed" = %s, "last" = %s, "user_id" = %s, "paid" = %s, "read" = %s, "article_id" = %s, "percent" = NULL WHERE "wiki_articleread"."id" = %s ' - 
PARAMS = (u'2015-04-05 12:55:49.708969', u'2015-04-05 12:55:49.708977', 2, True, True, 1, 11); 
args=(u'2015-04-05 12:55:49.708969', u'2015-04-05 12:55:49.708977', 2, True, True, 1, 11)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you have a boolean field. And you assign a string to it. Any string will resolve into True.
You need to do it like this:

```
 user.paid=False
```